# ASP.NET Core disable json patch

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

As stated in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1): adding NewtonsoftJson to the application now enables json patch support. I'm wondering how to add NewthonsoftJson without enabling json patch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JsonPatch support is handled through the [`NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.newtonsoftjsonpatchinputformatter) type. If you don't want this to be enabled, remove it from the [`InputFormatters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.inputformatters) collection. Here's an example:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson()
    .AddMvcOptions(o => o.InputFormatters.RemoveType<NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter>());
```